# vim search and replace expression by using previously matched pattern

Tags: vim

I have multiple lines in my data file like below

```
<some-text>:<fixed-string>
```

and I want to add space around the colon to feed to some other tool that expects this. I would like to do this in vim (not sed or other tools).

I was trying to do something like

```
%s/[a-z]*:<fixed-string>/\1 : <fixed-string>/gc
```

this doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help ? To take care of upper & lower case I tried using (\a)* thats next step.

Comment: Is your text actually in `<>` tags?

Comment: `%s/\([^:]\+\):fixed/\1 : fixed/gc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have any capture groups so you can not use `\1`. You either need to use capture groups, `\zs`&`\ze`, or look-behinds and look-aheads.

With a capture group:

```
:%s/\(\l*\):fixed/\1 : fixed/gc
```

With `\zs` and `\ze` to set the start and end of the match

```
:%s/\l*\zs:\zefixed/ : /gc
```

Look-aheads, `\@=`, and Look-behinds, `\@=`:

```
:%s/\(\l*\)\@<=:\(fixed\)\@=/ : /gc
```

Personally, I use use `\zs` and `\ze` as they are the simplest to reason about and use. I am also using `\l` which is short hand for `[a-z]`.

For more help see:

```
:h /\(
:h /\zs
:h /\@<=
:h /\@=
:h /\l
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

%s/\(.*\):fixed-string$/\1 : fixed-string/g

or this:

%s/:fixed-string$/ : fixed-string/g